# Thunderbird is removing line breaks on forwarded messages - what gives?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird

I have Thunderbird connected to my GMail account and when I forward a particular message the line breaks in a response I received from someone have been removed - the text is basically all on one line.  This only seems to be happening for that one email at this point.  Other emails seem to include line breaks.  I suspect I will see more of this the longer i use Thunderbird.  Are there any settings that I can configure to always include line breaks on forwarded messages?

When I "reply" on this same message the line breaks are included - it's only the "forward" that removes them.

Comment: What if you forward using Gmail? What was used to write/send the message? Maybe some odd Windows/Mac/Linux newline issue? Maybe a bad implementation of [format=flowed](http://joeclark.org/ffaq.html)? Any chance you could show some of the headers and the content of the message [using Thunderbird](http://email.about.com/od/mozillatips/qt/et043001.htm) or [using Gmail](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_view_source.htm)?

Comment: And: does it show as one long line in your Sent Items as well? Or maybe even already while editing? Is it just a single paragraph, or is it even concatenating multiple paragraphs into one long line? Does it show horizontal scrollbars? And I guess you're forwarding to yourself while testing? If not: what email client is the recipient of the forwarded message using?

Comment: Related to bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762475 ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Word wrap fails](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=682365&start=0) :

> This may sound a bit technical, but
>   Thunderbird is doing exactly what it
>   is supposed to do. When you have a
>   message in plain-text format which
>   doesn't come with flowed format, by
>   definition of the standard, the
>   receiving client is not allowed to
>   rewrap that message to fit the window
>   width. This is only possible if the
>   "format=flowed" attribute is set.
>   Consequently, Thunderbird assigns a
>   "Preformat" style to any quote which
>   comes from a plain-text message which
>   does not have that attribute set. It
>   would receive "Message Body" with
>   format=flowed set.
>
> A workaround for this is to highlight
>   the entire text immediately after
>   clicking on reply (i.e., CTRL+A), then
>   **change "Preformat" to "Body Text"** in
>   the left-most drop-down menu. This
>   should avoid the issue you observe. In
>   general though, if the sending client
>   formats the e-mail in a fixed way,
>   it's probably correct if Thunderbird
>   treats it this way. In the worst case,
>   there is always Edit > Rewrap, even
>   though it's not optimal either.

Comment: Wouldn't this then apply to both replying and forwarding?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes it would, if the same problem happened.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around the Thunderbird limitation (or whatever you want to call TB's strict adherence to the standard, at expense of good user experience).  I did this in Thunderbird 24.3.0, using a TB add-on:

- Stationery, version 0.8.4

I created a template for the Stationary that contains CSS instructions to allow line breaks in `<pre>` blocks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<style>
pre {
white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

(This code is taken directly from an anonymous comment in the thread [Word wrap fails](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=682365&start=0).)

One caveat with this is that it does not work when TB automatically generates and sends a message using the "forward message to" action of a message filter.  I haven't found any way to fix this problem in auto-forwarded messages.